# How can I create 3D surface of sine waves?

Tags: scripting, mathematics

I would like to make a surface that obeys the equation:

z = Asin(x) + Asin(y), 0<=z<=1; 0<=x<=2npi; 0<=y<=2npi

Where I would like to be able to change n to increase/decrease the number of cycles and change the amplitude A. I attempted to generate a sine wave via a script that I found; then I tried to extrude it, duplicate it, and then rotate one of the planes so that they intersected at a 90degree angle. The results were not very satisfying...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there's currently a way to add *surfaces*, but if you are okay with using meshes, you can use the *Extra objects* addon (it's not enabled by default).

To enable the addon, open the *User Preferences*, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>; then, switch to the *Add-ons*, search for "extra" and enable the one that reads "Add Mesh: Extra Objects", by checking the box.

[image]

Then, you can close the *User Preferences* window and, in the *3D View*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then select *Mesh>Math Function>Z Math Function*.

[image]

After that, in the *Toolbar* (<kbd>T</kbd>), you will find a box where to enter your function.

[image]

If you prefer, you can bring these options up by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image]

<sup>After you've entered your function, you can add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to make it smoother.</sup>

Comment: Where is the menu that I can access addons from ?

Comment: @Overzealous  *File* > *User Preferances*, or [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[U].