# Automatically "routing" a tube through a confined space

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, workflow, constraints

I have an **irregular curved funnel-like 3D space** and I need to "lay" a "**tube**" in it so it is **goes through the "middle"** of the funnel.

The sketch below shows a 2D section of a possible scene (the "tube" is shown in red, black represents "walls" of the space, blue is just a place where the "tube" is attached.):
[image: routing sketch]

**Is there a way to get Blender "route" the tube through the space (semi)automatically?**
By semi-automatically I mean manually selecting possible additional constraints (objects/points/...) or entering some parameter values and then letting the automated process do the rest.

I know I can use Curves to draw a path and manually adjust it so it fits, however, I would like to automate it as much as possible because the process will have to be done many times in different spaces (but generally similar in shape).
(I also know how to make a "tube" by adding a bevel to the curve as well as how to use hooks to modify it.)

**Could this be done by** first creating a curve (with high enough resolution) and then making it **"snap" to the "average" of the enclosing space** ...?

I'm new to Blender and 3D modelling but I'm quick in acquiring new skills.

Comment: I have updated the question to emphasize the point that I'd like to make the process of **routing** as **automated** as possible. Thank you Mentalist and PaulGonet for trying to hep, I appreciate it, I learned something from each of you.

Comment: What you are looking for is somewhat mathematically complex but of course possible through scripting. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIPohvB5vHI) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-H7n59YQCRM) are some approaches. Laplacian smooth and Decimate are implemented in blender as modifiers and could be used as a starting point.

Comment: If you know the mathemathic function which describes that curve it *should* be possible to use *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* addon with that function entered in value field, [like in this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46046/how-can-i-create-3d-surface-of-sine-waves). It won't be possible to edit that created mesh afterwards in this way as this is only possible to change using Last Operator menu though.

Comment: Thanks @user2859, that is interesting material, I'll look if there is a way to use it.

Comment: @MrZak, thanks, but unfortunately the funnel in this case cannot be described with a mathemathic function so cannot the resulting curve. Besides, if I had that, I would not need to route it. That is, unless i misunderstood your comment ...

Answer (score 4):

After giving this some thought, I have come up with another approach that might be a solution for you. It does require that the mesh of your space has quad topology, so that edge rings which flow along the tunnel can be selected and scaled in.

Of course, if you don't have control over the initial topology you will have to retopo first. I believe the RetopoFlow add-on would be the fastest way, if you need to do this.

### Select and Scale your Edge Rings

So you have your mesh object of your space:

[image: Tube space mesh object]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to make a duplicate of it, and move (<kbd>M</kbd>) it to a different layer.

In Edit Mode, with Edge Selection enabled, select only the edge rings. This can be done from the menu: **Select > Edge Rings**, or with the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>**RClick**. Do this until every edge ring is selected.

Set your Pivot Point to **Individual Origins**. This causes each selected edge loop to shrink toward its individual center when you scale them down, creating a path that passes through the center of the mesh.

[image: Set Pivot Center to Individual Origins]

Scale your edge rings down to zero. (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image: Scale edge rings to zero]

Press <kbd>W</kbd> **> Remove Doubles** to get rid of extra overlapping geometry.

### Smooth it Out

In Object Mode, add a **SubSurf Modifier** to your object to smooth it, if you want it to be smooth. Adjust the subdivision levels as desired.

[image: Add a Subdivision Surface Modifier]

Apply the SubSurf Modifier.

Convert your Mesh object to a Curve object. (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)

[image: Convert mesh to curve]

### Adjust your Curve Settings as Desired

[image: Adjust your curve settings]

*Above: A wireframe display of the original Mesh object, and the new Curve object, with both layers made visible together.*

That's it!

Comment: Alternative to RetopoFlow would be shrink wrapping your quad geometry to the tunnel.

Comment: @Mentalist, this does looks like a solution although I'll need to look into the retopo thing as the funnel shape I have is rather "organic". I can't do it today though, not sure about tomorrow. Will report on results as soon as I try it out.

Comment: @spacer Cool, please let us know how it works out for you. I am a fan of the Shrinkwrap method that Jerryno mentioned as well.

Comment: @Mentalist, Jerryno, I have finally found some time to test this and it looks very promising. However, I'm having two problems: A) shrink wrapping nicely around the curving funnel (I get "artifacts" spanning empty space outside the funnel) and B) selecting all edge loops automatically (without having to pick them out by hand one by one). Can you, please, give me some hints toward solving that?

Comment: @spacer Tip#1: Model your retopo mesh while the Shrinkwrap Modifier is on it and set it so you can see the effects in Edit Mode. By extruding one step at a time, and checking your modifier results along the way, you won't run into surprises later. Tip#2: Set the Shrinkwrap Modifier's Mode to Project, and the Direction to both Positive and Negative.

Comment: @Mentalist, thanks for the tips! However, I need to automate the process so cannot do manual extruding. I have already set the Shrinkwrap modifer's Mode as you suggested. Maybe Shrinkwrap is supposed to work that way. Or more likely I didn't understand something right - but what?

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds like you may need to code something custom to calculate volume and then operate accordingly. The bundled add-on "3D Print Toolbox" can calculate volume, but you also need to do something automated *with* that data. No tool for this immediately comes to mind, but I'll let you know if I get any more ideas. Maybe you could somehow modify [the script](http://www.blendernation.com/2007/05/11/python-script-calculating-the-volume-of-objects/).

Comment: Thanks @Menthalist, the script is a bit advanced for me at this stage, I'm afraid, but I'll keep the bookmark just in case I decide to revisit that approach. I will certainly appreciate it if you get back with any idea. It is just that I'm too novice with Blender that is hampering me. For example, Bisect tool makes such a nice "loops" that can be scaled - if only I could make bunch of these along funnel axis, connect them and scale them to zero like you did with edge loops ...

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram gave me a chuckle.  :-)

### Beveling Curves

There is a handy Bevel feature you can enable with Curve objects to get the effect you are describing.

In Object Mode press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to **Add > Curve > Bezier**

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch into Edit Mode for the Curve.

Then in the **Curve Context**, increase the **Bevel Depth**. Set the **Fill** mode to **Full** to make it round like a tube. Increase the **Resolution** so it will become rounded. Raise the **Resolution** of **Preview U** if you want to smooth out the length of the curve.

[image: A Beveled Curve, and its settings]

If you then need to convert this into a Mesh object you can do this from Object Mode by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and "Convert to Mesh".

[image: Converting a Curve to a Mesh]

### Taking it further

If you need something more complex than a simple wire or pipe you can experiment with Taper and Bevel objects to further shape your Curve. Or you can even model a custom Mesh object and use the Curve Modifier to stretch it along a Curve.

Comment: thank you, but I know about the Bevel feature (I will edit the question to clarify that). What I need is to - **automatically** or with some manual "help" - "route" the tube to nicely follow the funnel.  Maybe something along the idea of snapping the curve to "average" of the enclosing shape?

Comment: Oh, and yeah, maybe I should have added another bend so the diagram would look more like elephants front appendage rather than the middle one ;) lol

Answer (score 1):

You may easily control the tube using ***Hooks***.
[image]

Select the *Curve* and bevel it using *Bezier Circle*.
[image]
[image]

Now select the curve handle's center and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>-->*Hook to New Object*. Repeat the process with other handles. Now transforming, rotating and scaling the *hooks* you have a full controll over your tube.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @PaulGonet, I'm aware of hooks too. I realize now that I should have mentioned that in the question too, sorry. The post is useful though, I'm learning :) What I actually need is to **automatically** fit the tube within the funnel, then tweak it if necessary.